# ggplot fails to plot smallest points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I find when plotting points using `scale_size_area` the smallest points are omitted when the data ranges across several magnitudes.  Possible bug due to rounding to zero somewhere?

```
require(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x=1:4, y=rep(1,4), v=10^(1:4))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, size=v)) + geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = v), size=2, col='red') +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 50) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: If you increase `max_size` to e.g. 500 - you can see the point is gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does seem to be a bug, thusly therefore I've reported it: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1022

Comment: I think this might have something to do with ggplot's waiver function, called by `continuous_scale` in `scale_size_area`